# Quadratic Absolute Value Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Problem:

> Find all $x$ such that $|x^2+6x+6|=|x^2+4x+9|+|2x-3|$

I can't understand how to get started with this. I thought of squaring both sides of the equation to get rid of the modulus sign, but then couldn't understand how to deal with the following term:$$2|(x^2+4+9)(2x+3)|$$Any help or tips in general would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful tip:

If $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$, it holds only when $a\cdot b\ge 0$.

Therefore $(x^2+4x+9)(2x-3)\ge 0$. Now since, the discriminant of the quadratic is negative, it us always greater than $0$. So, you get your answer as $x \geq\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks very much Sir! Really short and neat answer!

Comment: The answer should be $x\ge\frac 32$.

Comment: I suppose the lesson is, if you see three polynomials in an equation like this, check to see whether one of them is the sum of the other two. But @mathlove, I thought your answer was a good demonstration of how one can solve the problem by direct means, even if one does not notice the relationship among the polynomials (or in case there is no such relationship).

Comment: @mathlove Oh, yes. Sorry for that.

Comment: @BetterWorld No problem. And please, I am no Sir. There is a high possibility, that I might be younger than you.

Comment: @DavidK: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You-know-me has already provided a good answer.

But I decided to undelete my answer in the hope that this answer might be of some help.

Since we have $x^2+4x+9=(x+2)^2+5\gt 0$, we have
$$|x^2+4x+9|=x^2+4x+9.$$

Then, since we have $x^2+6x+6=0\iff x=-3\pm\sqrt{3}$ and $2x-3=0\iff x=\frac 32$, separate it into three cases :

- For $x\lt -3-\sqrt 3$ or $-3+\sqrt 3\lt x\lt\frac 32$, we have $x^2+6x+6\gt 0$ and $2x-3\lt 0$. So we have $x^2+6x+6=x^2+4x+9-(2x-3)\iff x=\frac 32.$ So, in this case, there exists no such $x$.
- For $-3-\sqrt 3\le x\le -3+\sqrt 3$, we have $x^2+6x+6\le 0$ and $2x-3\le 0$. So we have $-(x^2+6x+6)=x^2+4x+9-(2x-3)\iff x^2+4x+9=0.$ So, in this case, there exists no such $x$.
- For $x\ge \frac 32$, we have $x^2+6x+6\ge 0$ and $2x-3\ge 0$, and we know that $x^2+6x+6=x^2+4x+9+2x-3$ always holds. So, in this case, we have $x\ge \frac 32$.

Hence, the answer is $x\ge\frac 32$.

Comment: Sir, I already noticed that. The reason I had was that the Discriminant was negative and that the coefficient of $x^2$ was positive, hence the polynomial is always positive. But Sir I still can't understand how to proceed with the problem. Could you please give another hint, Sir?

Comment: @BetterWorld: Take a look at my answer. I hope this helps.